# How would I refactor some code into functions?

Tags: php

So I have this code in php, getting some data from the database and displaying it on the page, but I want to display it only if the table is not empty.

This is what I have right now (all the question labels are hardcoded, they do not come from the DB):

```
<?php    

foreach ($answers as $a) {
    if ($a->q2 != '') {
        echo "<span class='question'>Question title?</span><span class='answer'>" . $a->q2 . '</span><br />';
    }

    if ($a->q3 != '') {
        echo "<span class='question'>Question label 2?</span><span class='answer'>" . $a->q3 . '</span><br />';
    }

    if ($a->q4 != '') {
        echo "<span class='question'>Another question label?</span><span class='answer'>" . $a->q4 . '</span><br />';
    }

    if ($a->q5 != '') {
        echo "<span class='question'>Quesiton label?</span><span class='answer'>" . $a->q5 . '</span><br />';
    }

    if ($a->q6 != '') {
        echo "<span class='question'>Quesiton label?</span><span class='answer'>" . $a->q5 . '</span><br />';
    }
}
```

I have a total of 19 questions, and I don't think this is the best approach to do it, how can I do it in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there's code duplicated here, so it's a good idea to try to eliminate it.

You could do:

```
function askQuestion($data, $question){
  if($data !='') {
     echo "<span class='question'>$question</span><span class='answer'>".$data.'</span><br />';
   }
}
```

and use it like:

```
foreach ( $answers as $a )   {
  askQuestion($a->q2, "Question title?");
  askQuestion($a->q3, "Question label 2?");
  // and so on
```

And, as a general rule of thumb: when you're about to refactore code, don't forget to put in place non regression tests first (because it would be too bad to break the code when we're trying to improve it).

Last advice: if you have to work with legacy codebases on a regular basis, you might to read [Working Effectively with legacy code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052), which gives a lot of practical tips to turn such codebases into stuff easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks man, all working good, and thank you for the advice :)